# get all elements under a mouse drag selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

You guys would have seen the image cropping tool which has a selection option (marque tool) created in javascript. 
http://marqueetool.net/examples/
Like this i want to get all elements under a selection.

For example in windows we have mouse group selection of files and folders by dragging the mouse to select multiple files. Like that i need to get all the elements under a selection in javascript. I can try other gimmicks but if there could be a simple tool then i can speed up my work.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the selectable ui , does exactly that lol ...